# interval dont attach after got cleared by condtion

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a slider with a play button witch change the slide image and there is a pause btn
when click play it do as i intended and when i pause it work fine but when i try to play again it dont work there is no interval after clearing it by pause btn but still i dont attach a new interval (btw logic behind increment is find i just paste part of code i am the problem is there there is previous and next btn which working fine but i cant replay after pause

```
const Controls = ({ setSlideIndex }) => {
  const interval = useRef();
  const COUNTER = 1000;


  const incrementSlide = () => {
    setSlideIndex((currIndex) => {
      return currIndex + 1 > 2 ? 0 : currIndex + 1;
    });
  };
  

  return (
    <div className="control-container">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          if (!interval.current) {
            interval.current = setInterval(() => incrementSlide(), COUNTER);
          }
        }}>Play</button>

      <button
        onClick={() => clearInterval(interval.current)}>Pause</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Controls;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you pause the interval using `clearInterval(interval.current)`, you should also set `interval.current` to `null`. This ensures that when you try to play again, the code correctly recognizes that there's no active interval, allowing it to start a new one.

```
const Controls = ({ setSlideIndex }) => {
  const interval = useRef(null); // Initialize interval as null

  const COUNTER = 1000;

  const incrementSlide = () => {
    setSlideIndex((currIndex) => {
      return currIndex + 1 > 2 ? 0 : currIndex + 1;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="control-container">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          if (!interval.current) {
            interval.current = setInterval(() => incrementSlide(), COUNTER);
          }
        }}
      >Play</button>

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          // Clear the interval and set interval.current back to null
          clearInterval(interval.current);
          interval.current = null;
        }}
      >Pause</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Controls;
```

Comment: that solved it ty , i thought clearing interval.current set in to undefined or null but when i log it value after clear interval it shows a random number for interval current what is this random number about?